# Unable to create array for recursive function

Tags: php, arrays, recursion

I have a simple function `checkReplies()` which checks the `reply_id` and if the `reply_id` is not equal to `0`, calls himself and checks again. Now I need to create a array ffor the outputs it generate, but I am unable to do it, the array outputs only the last element

```
function checkReplies( $rnid ){
    $r_notes = array();
    include_once('include/class.dbc.php');
    $dbo=new dbc();
    $db=$dbo->dbconnect();
    if( $rnid > 0 ): 
    $qry_rn = "SELECT note_subject,note_body,reply_note_id FROM tbl_notes WHERE note_id = '$rnid' ORDER BY note_date DESC";
    $rslt_rn = $dbo->executeQuery( $qry_rn );
    $reply = '<p style="border : none;">';
    $reply .= $rslt_rn[0]['note_subject'].'<br />'.$rslt_rn[0]['note_body'];
    $reply .= '('.$rslt_rn[0]['reply_note_id'].')';
    $reply .= '</p>';

    echo $reply;
    $r_notes[] = $reply;
    checkReplies( $rslt_rn[0]['reply_note_id'] );
    endif;
    return $r_notes;
}
$display = checkReplies( $rnid );
var_dump($display);
```

How to create the array of the outputs ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just give your array as an optional parameter of your function. And, return the recursive call of your function.

Almost all recursives functions are built the same way : at the beggining, a condition making your recursivity stop or continue : this is called the "terminating case".
Then, if this break condition is not true, make what you got to do and return the recursive call of the function.

```
function checkReplies( $rnid, &$r_notes = array() ){

    include_once('include/class.dbc.php');
    $dbo=new dbc();
    $db=$dbo->dbconnect();

    if($rnid == 0)
            return $r_notes;

    $qry_rn = "SELECT note_subject,note_body,reply_note_id FROM tbl_notes WHERE note_id = '$rnid' ORDER BY note_date DESC";
    $rslt_rn = $dbo->executeQuery( $qry_rn );

    $reply = '<p style="border : none;">';
    $reply .= $rslt_rn[0]['note_subject'].'<br />'.$rslt_rn[0]['note_body'];
    $reply .= '('.$rslt_rn[0]['reply_note_id'].')';
    $reply .= '</p>';

    echo $reply;

    $r_notes[] = $reply;

    return checkReplies( $rslt_rn[0]['reply_note_id'], $r_notes );

}


$display = checkReplies( $rnid );

var_dump($display);
```

Comment: :( its the same output coming

Comment: The array should probably be passed as a reference, only objects are automatically passed as references.

Comment: Edited, i forgot to give array as reference and to return the recursive call.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$r_notes = array_merge($r_notes, checkReplies( $rslt_rn[0]['reply_note_id'] ));
```

instead of

```
$r_notes[] = $reply;

checkReplies( $rslt_rn[0]['reply_note_id'] );
```

I edited, sorry for the error.

Comment: Warning : `Warning: array_merge() [function.array-merge]: Argument #1 is not an array in xxxx.php`

Comment: I used `$r_notes[] = array_merge($r_notes, checkReplies( $rslt_rn[0]['reply_note_id'] ));` But the O/P is like : 
`array
  0 => 
    array
      0 => 
        array
          0 => 
            array
              ...`

Comment: edited: `$r_notes = array_merge($r_notes, checkReplies( $rslt_rn[0]['reply_note_id'] ));` should work without the need to add a parameter to the function